# Find a matrix R α ∈ R 2 × 2 such that f ( x ) = f R α ( x ) for every x ∈ R 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this task.

Let α∈R be given.  Consider the linear map f:R^2→R^2,

```
   (x1   -->  ( x1·cos(α)−x2·sin(α)
    x2)        x1.sin(α)+x2·cos(α)).
```

a) Find a matrix Rα∈R2×2 such that f(x) =f Rα(x) for everyx∈R^2.

b)  Interpret the map f, i.e. state what it does to a given vector x∈R^2.

First I thought, I should use this rule 
**|A| = ad − bc** , but I think, It's already used . should i gave α a number like zero and then I will have a matrix and that's it?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read! You really have to learn MathJax. See [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a good tutorial.

Comment: You have a description there of the result of applying $f$ to an arbitrary column vector $(x_1,x_2)^T$. Can you write that result as a matrix times $(x_1,x_2)^T$ in any way?

Comment: @TonyK thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  The columns of the matrix are $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$.

For the second part, look at what happens to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and apply a little trigonometry.

Comment: How did you know that the columns of the m. are f(1,0)and f(0,1)?

Comment: This is always true.

Comment: can you give me a simple example to know how the result should look like ?

Comment: For the first column,  $f(1,0)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.  So we have $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &*\\\sin\theta &*\end{pmatrix}$, so far.  You try the second column.

Comment: it should be (x1,x2) if it's wrong please don't blame me XD XD XD

Comment: Right.   So when $(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)$, $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$.

Comment: mm does it mean (a) is done and we have found the matrix  the first column(cosθ,sinθ) ,the second column (x1,x2)?

Comment: No.  Plug in $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$, that is $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$, to get the second column.

Comment: mm if x1 =0 and x2=2 then we well get (-sinθ,cosθ) right ? so to find the first column we used f(1,0)  where x1=1 and x2=0 and to find the second one we use f(0,1) where x1=0 and x2=1

Comment: Now you've got it.

Comment: finally !!! thanks  :,)  how about the second part  ?

Comment: A little tricky but:  we saw that $(1,0)$ goes to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) $.  Try plotting both on the unit circle.   What angle does each make with the $x$-axis?   What can you conclude about their relationship?

Comment: do you mean (1,0) and (0,1) ? like (1,0) is the x axis and (0,1) is the y axis ?

Comment: Yes.  Now what about $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$?  What's one way to get from $(1,0)$, the $x-axis$, to $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$.  **Hint**  $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) $ makes an angle $\theta$ with $(1,0)$.

Comment: 90 degrees ? a right angle?

Comment: No...  The angle between them is $\theta$.  What's an easy way to make one land on top of the other?

Comment: What's an easy way to make one land on top of the other? (mm by increasing on the y axis ) I'm sorry I'm too bad with angles.

Comment: What's a mathematical term, beginning with r, related to turning.

Comment: mmm.. a radius ?

Comment: It starts ro...

Comment: Rotation ? XD XD

Comment: @Amerov. Yep.  Take another look and see if it makes any sense.

Comment: mmm does it have something to do with image and preimage?

Comment: Yeah.   $f$ or $A$ takes a vector and rotates it by an angle of $\theta$.  So the image and preimage differ by an angle of $\theta$.

Comment: mmm that's it ??

Comment: Yes.  That's it.

Comment: WOW , thank you very much for your helping ,(god bless you)

Comment: You're very welcome.